# Optimize Query - select statement in case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, correlated-subquery

I am trying to compare two sets of transactions. One is from a store log and the other is from the accounting records. I have a with statement that creates a table comparing both transactions and includes any that do not match. This table is called 'compare'

Now I am trying to figure out why certain values may not be present in compare so I am adding a case when statement. Here is what I have so far

```
select distinct *, 
case
   when (store_trans_id is not null and acctng_trans_id is not null) then 'Match'
   when (acctng_trans_id is null) then
      case 
        when exists (select 1 from compare cc where c.store_trans_id = cc.store_trans_id 
                                              and c.store_amount = cc.store_amount * -1) 
        then 'Store item transaction reversed'
      end
   else 'Research further'
end as 'Comparison'
from compare c
```

So when I only have the first case (Match), my query runs fast. When I add the second one it slows down. Essentially, what I am checking is if there is a store transaction that was rung up by the cashier and then canceled. If so, then the amount would be the same just the opposite ($5 versus -$5) and the store transaction id would be the same. I wouldn't expect a reversed transaction to be on the accounting record, since the item has not left the store. Any ideas on how to optimize the query run time? I have already added the additional case and moved from is not null to the when exists statement.

Comment: you are missing  alot of information for this kind of question please see the chapter here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Performance questions require an execution plan, table definitions, and index definitions. SQL is declarative and as such means you cannot obtain much in the way of performance information from the query itself.

Comment: I agree with the comments of the others that definitive help is only possible with more details.  That said, if you just want guesses, then my guess is that your comparison (`c.store_amount = cc.store_amount * -1`) is not sargable.  So it has to look at a buch of rows to run the `* -1` operation.  This means you cannot use an index seek.  Fixes to Sargability questions can be hard to answer, and (assuming I am right) I would need more information to help fix it.

Comment: I guess maybe a follow-up is beyond the scope of this. I am also asking if there is a another path to do what I am trying to do? I understand that the query itself being optimized includes indices, etc. But if there is an alternative path other than the one I am going down right now, I would be interested.

Comment: Just brainstorming, but you could consider a `SELECT` statement where you  `GROUP BY`  `store_trans_id` and adding a `HAVING` clause that returns rows with `count(store_trans_id) = 2` and where the `SUM` of `store_amount` equals 0.  Not quite the same, but depending on your requirements, may get you close to what you need.

Comment: @PretzelStands there will be multiple ways to solve the problem, but then thats not a suitable question this site - asking for alternative methods doesn't have a single clear answer. However you must have a reason for wanting an alternative, and that is probably a single problem which is a good question. So you need to tell us what the fundamental issue is you are trying to solve, and if its performance, give us the required information.

Comment: Do you *need* that `DISTINCT`? One would *assume* you have at least one column that is unique in your data, and as you have `*` if you have 2 or more rows that are **completely** identical then I would suggest that you have a data issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am going to try some of these ideas to see if I get a more suitable result.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't tested of course - let's say I'm taking a stab at it but you will have to let me know how it works.

main idea: get rid of the correlation subqueries and use sum/group by instead.

There should be 3 cases that may or may not cover all cases (I suppose they should but you can test out that theory by changing my inner join to a left join and see if there are null results on the left side).

Clearly, indexing may help a lot. Such as an index on store_trans_id (including accting_trans_id and store_amount)

I don't know what (if) there is a primary key in the table so in the queries where I have `c.PK <> c2.PK` that means the primary key on the table - though in this case the criteria can probably can also be omitted as the sum would still come out to 0 or non-zero and that's all we care about.

```
select c.*, c2.[Comparison]
from compare c
inner /* left */ join
(
    -- case 1: acctg_trans_id is not null
    select 
        store_trans_id,
        'Match' as [Comparison]
    from compare c
    where 
        store_trans_id is not null 
        and acctng_trans_id is not null
    union all
    -- case 2: acctg_trans_id is null and two store amounts sum to 0
    select 
        c.store_trans_id,
        'Store item transaction reversed' as [Comparison]
    from 
        compare c
        inner join compare c2
        on c.store_trans_id = c2.store_trans_id
        and c.PK <> c2.PK
    where 
        c.acctng_trans_id is null
        having sum(c.store_amount) = 0
    union all
    -- case 3: acctg_trans_id is null and two store amounts do not sum to 0
    select 
        c.store_trans_id,
        'Research further' as [Comparison]
    from 
        compare c
        inner join compare c2
        on c.store_trans_id = c2.store_trans_id
        and c.PK <> c2.PK
    where 
        c.acctng_trans_id is null
    having 
        sum(c.store_amount) <> 0
) c2
on c.store_trans_id = c2.store_trans_id
```